# golang http server handler and pointer issue

Tags: http, go

I am a bit lost with go-routines, http server, handlers and pointers.

1. I ve created a http server that accepts any request at any path, I am starting it in separate routine so main thread is not blocked

```
// main thread
// I want to bind to random port and read port later
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")

rh := requestHandler{} // look at point 2)
s := &http.Server{
        Handler:        rh,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
go func() {
        err := s.Serve(listener)
        ...
    }()
```

2. `rh` is a Handler interface so I ve created a struct following the interface

```
type requestHandler struct {
    values []string
}

func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, givenRequest *http.Request) {
    log.Println("DEBUG : handling request", givenRequest.Method, givenRequest.URL, givenRequest.RequestURI)
    log.Println("DEBUG : headers", givenRequest.Header)

    for _, value := range rh.values { // <----- values are always empty
    }
}
```

3. lets add some values to handler

```
// main thread
rh.values = append(rh.values, "one)
```

obviously this doesn't work as Server is copying Handler and `rh` variable from main thread has different pointer than `s.Handler`, but this is OK.

What I dont understand is that also `rh` in `func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, givenRequest *http.Request)` has different pointer than `s.Handler`.

how can I pass anything to requestHandler.values from main thread so those values can be read in callback function ? I ve tried using channels but I cannot access pointer/ref to right `rh`. Is it because each request is also spawn in new routine and handler is also copied ?

sample code

```
type MyServer struct {
    Port           int
    pid            *http.Server
    requestHandler requestHandler
}

func (s *MyServer) addValue(value string) {
    s.requestHandler.values = append(s.requestHandler.values, value)
}

func InitializeServer() *MyServer {
    rh := requestHandler{}

    listener := bindToNextFreePort()
    s := &http.Server{
        Handler:        rh,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    startServer(s, listener)

    currentPort := getTcpPort(listener)
    log.Println("My Server Initialized on ", currentPort)
    return &MyServer{
        pid:            s,
        Port:           currentPort,
        requestHandler: rh,
    }
}
func startServer(s *http.Server, listener net.Listener) {
    go func() {
        log.Println("starting Mock Server")
        err := s.Serve(listener)
    }()
}

type requestHandler struct {
    values []string
}

func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, givenRequest *http.Request) {
    log.Println("DEBUG : handling request", givenRequest.Method, givenRequest.URL, givenRequest.RequestURI)
    log.Println("DEBUG : headers", givenRequest.Header)

    for key, value := range rh.values {

    }
}

func bindToNextFreePort() net.Listener {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return listener
}
```

Comment: Can you show code that actually compiles? This `func (rh *requestHandler) ServeHTTP(....`, and this `rh := requestHandler{}` will cause this `Handler:        rh,` to fail at compile time.

Comment: You should also show how `rh` is being shared. Is being passed as a function argument to other parts of the code, or is it in a parent scope and accessed directly by those other parts of the code.

Comment: ... as an example to corroborate the claim in the top comment, try running this: https://play.golang.com/p/mUgUIjgQObi.

Comment: @mkopriva updated the question with more code. I understand that your comment about compilation relates to `func (rh *requestHandler) ServeHTTP` which should be `func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP` - my bad I ve was writing it without looking and code, my case compiles and runs.

Comment: Change `rh` to be a pointer. In `InitializeServer` as the variable, but also in `ServeHTTP` as the receiver.

Comment: i.e. `rh := &requestHandler{ ... ` and `func (rh *requestHandler) ServeHTTP(...`.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/j-OiiRKy_bz

Comment: @mkopriva so can you explain why without making it pointer it doesnt work?? is rh copied every time new connection is established ?

Comment: The value of a variable is copied on assignment, including struct field assignment `Handler: rh,`. (https://play.golang.com/p/1EYrqeqwyFd)

Comment: @mkopriva that's understood (I wrote about it in my question) but why `rh` from `func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP` has different poitner than s.Handler which should be same after instantiation of http.Server

Comment: What pointer? `rh` in `func (rh requestHandler) ServeHTTP` is not a pointer, and why do you believe it should be the same after, by assigment, `s.Handler` is a copy of the original `rh` before you ever appended any values to it?

Comment: If you have value `V`, and then you create a copy of it, say `V1`, and then you modify the original `V`, do you believe the modification should be reflected automatically in `V1`? If that's how you believe values in Go work then you've misunderstood.

Comment: Inside `InitializeServer` you have the original `rh := ...`, then you create one copy `Handler: rh,` and then you create another copy `requestHandler: rh,`. So basically you have 3 separate values of `requestHandler`, modifying one of these will not modify the others. Modifying `*MyServer.requestHandler` will not modify `*MyServer.pid.Handler`, and vice versa.

Comment: `and then you create another copy requestHandler: rh,` this what I was missing yes I am making assignment here as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be quite simple, I've closed my eyes for this assignment here

```
return &MyServer{
    pid:            s,
    Port:           currentPort,
    requestHandler: rh,
}
```

Which led to yet another copy.